# ASP.NET Exception-Handling: ExceptionFilterAttribute vs Overwrite ExecuteAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET, Microsoft suggests us to use ExceptionFilterAttribute to handling exceptions. [Exception Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

But I think we have other ways to handling it. But I am not sure what differences between those things:

- Why shouldn't we use this way?

**For example: I can handle by overwriting ExecuteAsync of Controller class:**

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);

        if (response.IsFaulted)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage errorResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            if (response.Exception.InnerException is NotImplementedException)
            {
                errorResponse.Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ErrorCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Message = response.Exception.InnerExceptions }));
            }

            errorResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            return errorResponse;
        }

        return await response;
    }
}
```

Thanks for supporting!

Answer (score 2):

First, it's a matter of paradigm: [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Second, the exception filters are designed specifically to handle exceptions and nothing else (following [Single Responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Overriding `ExecuteAsync` to handle exceptions is like taking the longer, more complicated route. You have to write more code and have more possibilities to break something. Like:

- are you sure the task from `base.ExecuteAsync` is always completed before you check `IsFaulted`?
- are you sure the framework isn't doing any additional work when handling exceptions through filters?